# Spring Boot HIbernate Issue: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement with ddl-auto=create-drop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am a novice with Spring and Hibernate and have tried everything I could find to fix this with no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am currently following a sample project in a book, and am getting an error that says "GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement." I am using a MariaDB database, and my hibernate dialect is org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect.

The query causing this issue is

```
alter table car drop foreign key FK2mqqwvxtowv4vddvtsmvtiqa2;
```

If I try to run this query directly in the database it works fine. I have the ddl-auto property set to create-drop, so maybe it is trying to execute this query when the car table has been dropped and is not there? I'm not sure why it would do that or how to turn off this behavior if that is the problem.

If I change ddl-auto to validate or update, the application fails to run at all. If I change it to create, it works fine and I get no errors.

With create-drop, the application does connect to the database and all my tables are created. The tables are still defined as they should be, but the error remains.

Console output:

```
2018-07-25 16:56:24.229  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication   : Starting CardatabaseApplication on Northstar-2.local with PID 12414 2018-07-25 16:56:24.230  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-25 16:56:24.278  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@42e3f007: startup date [Wed Jul 25 16:56:24 AKDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-25 16:56:25.134  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2018-07-25 16:56:25.535  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5303d26] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-25 16:56:25.850  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-25 16:56:25.875  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-25 16:56:25.875  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-07-25 16:56:25.883  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/tatiana/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.025  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-25 16:56:26.025  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1750 ms
2018-07-25 16:56:26.155  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.156  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.156  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.156  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.156  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.156  INFO 12414 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.288  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-07-25 16:56:26.354  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-07-25 16:56:26.385  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-25 16:56:26.401  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-07-25 16:56:26.467  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
2018-07-25 16:56:26.469  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-07-25 16:56:26.504  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-07-25 16:56:26.602  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2018-07-25 16:56:27.062  WARN 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.packt.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication.main(CardatabaseApplication.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=342) Table 'cardb.car' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:177) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:334) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:386) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'cardb.car' doesn't exist
Query is: alter table car drop foreign key FK2mqqwvxtowv4vddvtsmvtiqa2
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.LogQueryTool.exceptionWithQuery(LogQueryTool.java:119) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:199) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:328) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 44 common frames omitted

[ . . . Mapping details here, omitted]

2018-07-25 16:56:27.118  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@23352c6f'
2018-07-25 16:56:27.121  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-25 16:56:28.047  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7ec73b7e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6f233313, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e641fa3, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7c5a0312, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@176619be, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@26add7c1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@4030f929, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2ea06fad, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6ce594ae, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6159e3c1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@51157300, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5be9c504, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4506e3d3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1f44843c]
org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2018-07-25 16:56:28.632  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-07-25 16:56:28.668  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-25 16:56:28.670  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-07-25 16:56:28.676  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-07-25 16:56:28.712  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-07-25 16:56:28.715  INFO 12414 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.cardatabase.CardatabaseApplication   : Started CardatabaseApplication in 4.726 seconds (JVM running for 5.165)
```

Here is the code on my repo:
https://github.com/Kallaste/spring_login_server_example_so

Comment: change the ddl-auto=update and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Can you try to remove "cardb." in your query? The problem is Hibernate could not find out any table named "cardb.car"

Comment: As I said in the post, I did use ddl-auto=update and ddl-auto=validate, and the application fails to run. I'm pretty sure this is due to the fact that I am using a CommandLineRunner method in my main class to seed test data, and the old data is still in the tables, so there are duplicates that violate constraints. In any event, the create-drop should be able to work, right? I don't want to work around it, but use it as intended (however that is).

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t worry about it if your application still runs. Hibernate throws a lot of ‘informative’ errors on startup. It just tries to figure out what it has to do to get the database in a state where your application can run.

If the app runs fine if you use `create-drop` or just `create`, then try running it with `create` just once so everything is generated and then change it to `validate` so the next time it only validates your database schema.

In a production environment you would generally not let Hibernate update the database schema by itself but manually apply changes and migrate data anyway, unless you’re very sure the changes would be applied correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `create` the first time you run your application, but the next runs have to have `update`.

When you use `create` you create the schema and destroy the previous data.
And `create-drop` destroy the schema in the end of the session. `update` only update you schema.

Answer (score 2):

`update` should still be valid. If tables don't exist, it will behave as create.

Are you sure your DB and DBDialect match?

Answer (score 0):

Add @Table annotation like below

`@Table(name="car")` in car entity. Always give name to table .

Note:

1) When ddl-auto=create-drop and if you don't have @Table(name="car") always you will get this exception.

2) When ddl-auto=create-drop and if you have @Table(name="car") the first time alone you will get this exception.

So try to change the ddl-auto value to other than create-drop . May be you can use "create" or "update"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I still get the error when I add @Table(name="car"). Also, as I mentioned above, if I change the ddl-auto value to "update" or "validate," the application will not run at all. It gives a duplicate entry SQLException regarding my seed data (in a CommandLineRunner method in my main class).

Comment: However, ddl-auto=create is working fine. I think I will just use that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** =**update** instead of **create-drop** in application.properties file.
 Because It is dropping the database at the start of the application and so it won't find the required events table to alter anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you don't have permissions on the database user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).